# Training GAN in keras with .fit_generator()

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have been training a conditional GAN architecture similar to Pix2Pix with the following training-loop:

```
for epoch in range(start_epoch, end_epoch):
    for batch_i, (input_batch, target_batch) in enumerate(dataLoader.load_batch(batch_size)):
                fake_batch= self.generator.predict(input_batch)

                d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(target_batch, valid)
                d_loss_fake = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(fake_batch, invalid)
                d_loss = np.add(d_loss_fake, d_loss_real) * 0.5

                g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch([target_batch, input_batch], [valid, target_batch])
```

Now this works well, but it is not very efficient as the dataloader quickly becomes a bottleneck time-wise.
I have looked into the .fit_generator() function that keras provides, which allows the generator to run in a worker thread and runs much faster.

```
self.combined.fit_generator(generator=trainLoader,
                                    validation_data=evalLoader
                                    callbacks=[checkpointCallback, historyCallback],
                                    workers=1,
                                    use_multiprocessing=True)
```

It took me some time to see that this was incorrect, I wasn't training my generator and discriminator separately anymore and the discriminator wasn't being trained at all since it it set to `trainable = False` in the combined model, essentially ruining any kind of adversarial loss, and I might as well train my generator by itself with `MSE`.

Now my question is if there is some work around, such as training my discriminator inside a custom callback, which is triggered each batch of the .fit_generator() method? It is possible to implement to create custom callbacks, like this for example:

```
class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    discriminator.train_on_batch()
```

Another possibility would be to parallelise the original training loop, but I am afraid that I have no time to do that right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: There are built in enqueuers for this:**

- `tf.keras.utils.SequenceEnqueuer`: [SequenceEnqueuer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/SequenceEnqueuer)
- `tf.keras.utils.OrdereEnqueuer`: [OrderedEnqueuer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/OrderedEnqueuer)

You can check a quick way to use them in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214794/2097240

---

**Old answer:**

I created this parallelized iterator exactly for that purpose. I use it in my trainings;

This is how you use it:

```
for epoch, batchIndex, originalBatchIndex, xAndY in ParallelIterator(
                                       generator, 
                                       epochs, 
                                       shuffle_bool, 
                                       use_on_epoch_end_from_generator_bool,
                                       workers = 8, 
                                       queue_size=10):
    #loop content
    x_train_batch, y_train_batch = xAndY
    model.train_on_batch(x_train_batch, y_train_batch)
```

The `generator` there should be your `dataloader`, but it needs to be a `keras.utils.Sequence`, not just a yield generator.

But it's not very complicated to adapt if you need. (I just don't know if it will parallelize properly, though, I don't know if yield loops can be properly parallelized)
In the iterator definition below, you should replace:

- `len(keras_sequence)` with `steps_per_epoch`
- `keras_sequence[i]` with `next(keras_sequence)`
- `use_on_epoch_end = False`

And this is the iterator definition:

```py
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp

#A generator that wraps a Keras Sequence and simulates a `fit_generator` behavior for custom training loops
#It will also work with any iterator that has `__len__` and `__getitem__`.    
def ParallelIterator(keras_sequence, epochs, shuffle, use_on_epoch_end, workers = 4, queue_size = 10):

    sourceQueue = mp.Queue()                     #queue for getting batch indices
    batchQueue = mp.Queue(maxsize = queue_size)  #queue for getting actual batches 
    indices = np.arange(len(keras_sequence))     #array of indices to be shuffled

    use_on_epoch_end = 'on_epoch_end' in dir(keras_sequence) if use_on_epoch_end == True else False
    batchesLeft = 0

#     printQueue = mp.Queue()                      #queue for printing messages
#     import threading
#     screenLock = threading.Semaphore(value=1)
#     totalWorkers= 0

#     def printer():
#         nonlocal printQueue, printing
#         while printing:
#             while not printQueue.empty():
#                 text = printQueue.get(block=True)
#                 screenLock.acquire()
#                 print(text)
#                 screenLock.release()

    #fills the batch indices queue (called when sourceQueue is empty -> a few batches before an epoch ends)
    def fillSource():
        nonlocal batchesLeft

#         printQueue.put("Iterator: fill source - source qsize = " + str(sourceQueue.qsize()))
        if shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(indices)

        #puts the indices in the indices queue
        batchesLeft += len(indices)
#         printQueue.put("Iterator: batches left:" + str(batchesLeft))
        for i in indices:
            sourceQueue.put(i)

    #function that will load batches from the Keras Sequence
    def worker():
        nonlocal sourceQueue, batchQueue, keras_sequence, batchesLeft
#         nonlocal printQueue, totalWorkers
#         totalWorkers += 1
#         thisWorker = totalWorkers

        while True:
#             printQueue.put('Worker: ' + str(thisWorker) + ' will try to get item')
            index = sourceQueue.get(block = True) #get index from the queue
#             printQueue.put('Worker: ' + str(thisWorker) + ' got item ' +  str(index) + " - source q size = " + str(sourceQueue.qsize()))

            if index is None:
                break

            item = keras_sequence[index] #get batch from the sequence
            batchesLeft -= 1
#             printQueue.put('Worker: ' + str(thisWorker) + ' batches left ' + str(batchesLeft))

            batchQueue.put((index,item), block=True) #puts batch in the batch queue
#             printQueue.put('Worker: ' + str(thisWorker) + ' added item ' + str(index) + ' - queue: ' + str(batchQueue.qsize()))

#         printQueue.put("hitting end of worker" + str(thisWorker))

#       #printing pool that will print messages from the print queue
#     printing = True
#     printPool = mp.Pool(1, printer)

    #creates the thread pool that will work automatically as we get from the batch queue
    pool = mp.Pool(workers, worker)    
    fillSource()   #at this point, data starts being taken and stored in the batchQueue

    #generation loop
    for epoch in range(epochs):

        #if not waiting for epoch end synchronization, always keeps 1 epoch filled ahead
        if (use_on_epoch_end == False):
            if epoch + 1 < epochs: #only fill if not last epoch
                fillSource()

        for batch in range(len(keras_sequence)):

            #if waiting for epoch end synchronization, wait for workers to have no batches left to get, then call epoch end and fill
            if use_on_epoch_end == True:
                if batchesLeft == 0:
                    keras_sequence.on_epoch_end()
                    if epoch + 1 < epochs:  #only fill if not last epoch
                        fillSource()
                    else:
                        batchesLeft = -1   #in the last epoch, prevents from calling epoch end again and again

            #yields batches for the outside loop that is using this generator
            originalIndex, batchItems = batchQueue.get(block = True)
            yield epoch, batch, originalIndex, batchItems


#         print("iterator epoch end")
#     printQueue.put("closing threads")

    #terminating the pool - add None to the queue so any blocked worker gets released
    for i in range(workers):
        sourceQueue.put(None)
    pool.terminate()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
#     printQueue.put("terminated")

#     printing = False
#     printPool.terminate()
#     printPool.close()
#     printPool.join()


    del pool,sourceQueue,batchQueue
#     del printPool, printQueue
```

Comment: I haven't had time to try your answer yet, but might as well award the bounty before it expires. Thank you for your response in any case!

Comment: Thank you :D -- It does work, I'm using it right now in my code :))

Comment: I finally found the time to check out your iterator, and it's super smart. Thanks! Your answer was definitely worth the 50 rep :D

Comment: @AhmadMoussa , I found out two enqueuers that do this job with less code :), updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update! That's super nice from you, I would upvote you again if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Although the there is already an solution to your problem, I want to answer your original question if you can train your discriminator in a custom callback inside your combined model.

The simple answer is **Yes**.

Be careful when compiling your models (Discriminator and the combined model) and follow the steps stated here: 
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8585#issuecomment-385729276

Call on your combined model fit or fit generator:

```
combined_model.fit_generator(train_loader, epochs, callbacks=[gan_callback])
```

gan_callback is a custom callback class overwriting on_batch_end where you call (as you stated)

```
def on_batch_end(self, batch_idx, logs=None):
    logs_disc = model_disc.train_on_batch(x, y)
```

To get the discriminator model inside your callback either provide it at construction time as a parameter or get it via the inherited self.model (model.layers) variable.

**I think this solution is elegant when you want to output your losses and metrics to tensorboard.**

Inside your on_batch_end function in the gan_callback you have both logs (containing the values of your losses and metrics) directly at hand:

- logs_disc from the discriminator
- logs from the generator, which are a parameter to on_batch_end()

Depending on your configuration this can produce a warning which can be ignored:

```
UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch update (0.151899).    Check your callbacks.
```