# Is the order of batches guaranteed in Keras' OrderedEnqueuer?

Tags: keras, queue, sequence

I have a custom `keras.utils.sequence` which generates batches in a specific (and critical) order.

However, I need to parellelise batch generation across multiple cores. Does the name '`OrderedEnqueuer`' imply that the order of batches in the resulting queue is guaranteed to be the same as the order of the original `keras.utils.sequence`?

My reasons for thinking that this order is not guaranteed:

1. OrderedEnqueuer uses python `multiprocessing`'s `apply_async` internally.
2. Keras' docs explicitly say that `OrderedEnqueuer` is guaranteed not to duplicate batches - but not that the order is guaranteed.

My reasons for thinking that it is:

1. The name!
2. I understand that `keras.utils.sequence` objects are indexable.
3. I found test scripts on Keras' github which appear to be designed to verify order - although I could not find any documentation about whether these were passed, or whether they are truly conclusive.

If the order here is not guaranteed, I would welcome any suggestions on how to parellelise batch preparation while maintaining a guaranteed order, with the proviso that it must be able to parellelise arbitrary python code - I believe e.g `tf.data.Dataset` API does not allow this (`tf.py_function` calls back to original python process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's ordered.

Check it yourself with the following test.

First, let's create a dummy `Sequence` that returns just the batch index after waiting a random time (the random time is to assure that the batches will not be finished in order):

```
import time, random, datetime
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class DataLoader(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __len__(self):
        return 10
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2))
        #you could add a print here to see that it's out of order
        return i
```

Now let's create a test function that creates the enqueuer and uses it.
The function takes the number of workers and prints the time taken as well as the results as returned.

```
def test(workers):
    enq = tf.keras.utils.OrderedEnqueuer(DataLoader())
    enq.start(workers = workers)
    gen = enq.get()

    results = []
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(30):
        results.append(next(gen))
    enq.stop()
    print('test with', workers, 'workers took', datetime.datetime.now() - start)
    print("results:", results)
```

Results:

```
test(1)
test(8)
```

> test with 1 workers took 0:00:45.093122
>   results: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>   test with 8 workers took 0:00:09.127771
>   results: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Notice that:

- 8 workers is way faster than 1 worker -> it is parallelizing ok
- results are ordered for both cases

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much for the clear and well-explained response!

Comment: @hanneswhittingham , :) - Happy to help. Please mark this as "answered" if you consider it answers your question.